# Allow Whitespace sections ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have an antlr4 grammar designed for an a domain specific language that is embedded into a text template.

There are two modes:

- Text (whitespace should be preserved)
- Code (whitespace should be ignored)

Sample grammar part:

```
template
  :  '{' templateBody '}'
  ;

templateBody
  : templateChunk*
  ;

templateChunk
  : code # codeChunk // dsl code, ignore whitespace
  | text # textChunk // any text, preserve whitespace
  ;
```

The rule for `code` may contain a nested reference to the `template` rule. So the parser must support nesting whitespace/non-whitespace sections.

Maybe **lexer modes** can help - with some drawbacks:

- the code sections must be parsed in another compiler pass
- I doubt that nested sections could be mapped correctly

Yet the most promising approach seems to be the **manipulation of hidden channels**.

**My question:** Is there a best practice to fill these requirements? Is there an example grammar, that has already solved similar problems?

**Appendix:**

The rest of the grammar could look as following:

```
code
  : '@' function
  ;

function
  : Identifier '(' argument ')'
  ;

argument
  : function
  | template
  ;

text
  : Whitespace+
  | Identifier
  | .+
  ;

Identifier
  : LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*
  ;

Whitespace
  : [ \t\n\r] -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;

fragment LETTER
    : [a-zA-Z]
    ;

fragment DIGIT
    : [0-9]
    ;
```

In this example `code` has a dummy implementation pointing out that it can contain nested code/template sections. Actually `code` should support

- multiple arguments
- primitive type Arguments (ints, strings, ...)
- maps and lists
- function evaluation
- ...

Comment: You can push/pop lexer modes, so you should be fine with them. But you'd have to post the `code` and `text` rules so we can see if you really need a second pass or not.

Comment: This probably works fine if the delimiters of `text` are context insensitive (i.e. if any occurance of these delimiters opens/closes a `text` section). I gets difficult, if it depends on the parser state whether the delimiters delimit a `text` or another language structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem at the end:

The idea is to enable/disable whitespace in a parser rule:

```
 templateBody : {enableWs();} templateChunk* {disableWs();};
```

So we will have to define `enableWs` and `disableWs` in our parser base class:

```
public void enableWs() {
    if (_input instanceof MultiChannelTokenStream) {
        ((MultiChannelTokenStream) _input).enable(HIDDEN);
    }
}

public void disableWs() {
    if (_input instanceof MultiChannelTokenStream) {
        ((MultiChannelTokenStream) _input).disable(HIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Now what is this `MultiChannelTokenStream`?

- Antlr4 defines a `CommonTokenStream` which is a token stream reading only from **one channel**.
- `MultiChannelTokenStream` is a token stream reading from the **enabled channels**. For implementation I took the source code of CommonTokenStream and replaced each reference to the `channel` by `channels` (equality comparison gets contains comparison)

An example implementation with the grammar above could be found at [antlr4multichannel](https://github.com/almondtools/antlr4multichannel)

Comment: Nice solution. [Here's a different approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26533266/3764814) if you always need the full text, but your solution allows for more scenarios (for instance you could enable whitespace but disable comments).