# Ignoring whitespace on a per-parser-rule basis in Antlr4

Tags: parsing, whitespace, antlr4, xtext

My grammar must ignore whitespaces for the most part, except in certain contexts. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524952/ignoring-whitespace-in-certain-parts-in-antlr4) advises to define specific lexer rules to handle the exceptions I want.

The problem is that (I think) I cannot handle such cases at the lexer level, since they seem to be triggered high at the parser level.

To be more specific: I want to recognize something like

```
MyRule:
   MyParseTree1 Operator MyParseTree2 // WS is skipped
   | MyParseTree1 WS SensitiveOperator WS MyParse // WS carries meaning
```

keeping in mind that I have a *WS -> skip* rule because in most of my grammar whitespaces should be skipped.

In [Xtext](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html), rules can specify on a rule-scoped basis what hidden tokens apply within the rule's scope:

```
MyRule (hidden COMMENTS):
  ... // WS reaches the parser, comments don't

MyRule2 (hidden WS, COMMENTS):
  ... // WS is skipped, comments too
```

But I am clueless with antlr4.

Comment: Can't you also match the space(s) in your SensitiveOperator?

Comment: XText is a paved over version of Antlr3. Lots of concepts don't apply to Antlr4. In any event, looks like you are trying to solve a lexer issue in the parser. Provide the actual lexer rule for `SensitiveOperator`. Confirm that the real issue is that it requires leading and trailing `WS`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I haven't had the time to check your suggestions yet, but I believe defining operators as blank-aware at the lexer level is the way to go. As soon as I check it, I will come back and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to skip certain `Tokens` depending on the grammar context you should have a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504124/ambiguous-call-expression-in-antlr4-grammar/45511037#45511037) where the given procedure is described for skipping whitespace (as you want to do it).

Comment: Thanks. Please see my comment above.

Comment: Accepting your answer because it's a valid alternativeto just-lexer rules (which I haven't been able to make work yet).