# ANTLR4: context-sensitive spaces?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4, lexer

In a grammar I would like to implement texts without string delimiting `xxx`.
The idea is to define things like

```
a = xxx;
```

instead of

```
a ="xxx";
```

to simplify typewriting. Otherwise there should be variable definitions
and other kind of stuff as well.

As a first approach I experimented with this grammar:

```
    grammar SpaceNoSpace;

    prog: stat+;

    stat:
     'somethingelse' ';'
    | typed description* content
    ;

    typed:
     'something' '-'  
         | 'anotherthing' '-'
    ;

    description: 
             'someSortOfDetails'  COLON  ID HASH  
         | 'otherSortOfDetails' COLON  ID HASH 
    ;

    content:    
        contenttext ';'
    ;

    contenttext: 
         (~';')*
    ;

    COLON: ':' ;
    HASH: '#';
    SEMI: ';';
    SPACE: ' ';
    ID: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+;
    WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
    ANY_CHAR : . ;
```

This works fine for input files like this:

```
    something-someSortOfDetails: aVariableName#
    this is the content of this;

    anotherthing-someSortOfDetails: aVariableName#
    here spaces are accepted as much        as you like;

    somethingelse;
```

But modifying the last line to

```
    somethingelse ;
```

leads to a syntax error:

```
    line 7:15 extraneous input ' ' expecting ';'
```

This probably reveals that the lexer rule

```
  WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

is not applied, (but the SPACE rule???).

Otherwise, if I delete the SPACE lexer-rule,  the space
in "somethingelse ;" is ignored (by lexer-rule WS), so that the parser rule 
stat : somethingelse  as a consequence is detected correctly.
But as a consequence of the deleted SPACE-rule the content text will be reduced to single in-between-spaces, 
so "this          here" will be reduced to "this here".

This is not a big problem, but nevertheless it is  an
interesting question:

is it possible to implement context-sensitive WS or SPACE
lexer rules:

within the  content parser-rule any space should be preserved, 
in any other rule spaces should be ignored.

Is this possible to define such a context-sensitive lexer-rule behavior in ANTLR4?

Comment: this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060496/allow-whitespace-sections-antlr4
seems to be very close to an answer.
Maybe  this coulld be also be done within the grammar?
Or even easier?

Comment: That looks like an answer to me, which would make this question a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [Lexer Modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md)? The section with **mode(), pushMode(), popMode** is probably interesting for you.

Yet I think that lexer modes are more a problem than a solution. Their purpose is to use (parser) context in the lexer. Consequently one should discard the paradigm of separating lexer and parser - and use a PEG-Parser instead.

Comment: " Modes are not allowed within combined grammars", therefore I don't now how to use it here. The ANTLR4 book gives an example,where for XML the modes selection is triggered by '<' and '>', both are lexer rules. 
I tried to modfiy the content rule:
content:    
->mode(WITH_SPACE)
        contenttext ';'
->mode(WITHOUT_SPACE)
;
but exactly this seems to be forbidden (no chance to place the switch
into a parser rule???).

Comment: Is there maybe a chance apply the WS rule (kill every space in the first step) and let the content parser get the belonging spaces get back
form the hidden channel (insert them into the content character stream
after parsing)?
I don't know how to get access to the hidden character, and especially not, if it is possible to access them rule-specific?

Comment: Most (all?) combined grammars can be transformed to separate lexer/parser grammars. Maybe this is an option for you. Your second suggestion is exactly what I did in the posting you already mentioned.

Comment: your solution to your own question seems to be the even the most easy way to solve it since modes could not be applied to the parser rule.
I thought there would be a way to use modes or channels without writing  code (just with pure grammar statements).
But as is seems this is not posible. So your code allows a really
easy implementation of the rule within the grammar rules. Thanks!

Comment: Then we should mark this question as duplicate, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `SPACE` rule is before the `WS` rule, the lexer is returning a space token to the parser. The ' ' is not being being placed on the hidden channel.

Comment: This does not answer the question, "is it possible to define such a context-sensitive lexer-rule behavior in ANTLR4?".

Comment: Well, yes, of course.  You basically have it except you stumbled over the `SPACE` rule. Might be better from a general design point of view to use lexical modes to isolate exactly where and how you want to handle whitespace sensitivity.