# Ambiguous call expression in ANTLR4 grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4, ambiguity

I have a simple grammar (for demonstration)

```
grammar Test;


program
    :   expression* EOF
    ;


expression
    :   Identifier
    |   expression '(' expression? ')'
    |   '(' expression ')'
    ;


Identifier
    :   [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9?]*
    ;

WS
    :   [ \r\t\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

Obviously the second and third alternatives in the `expression` rule are ambiguous. I want to resolve this ambiguity by permitting the second alternative only if an expression is **immediately followed** by a `'('`.

So the following

```
bar(foo)
```

should match the second alternative while

```
bar
(foo)
```

should match the 1st and 3rd alternatives (even if the token between them is in the HIDDEN channel).

How can I do that? I have seen these ambiguities, between call expressions and parenthesized expressions, present in languages that have no (or have optional) expression terminator tokens (or rules) - [example](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/ecmascript/ECMAScript.g4)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to temporary "unhide" whitespace in your second alternative. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060496/allow-whitespace-sections-antlr4/29115489#29115489) for how this can be done.

With that solution your code could look somthing like this

```
expression
    :   Identifier
    |   {enableWS();} expression '(' {disableWS();} expression? ')'
    |   '(' expression ')'
    ;
```

That way the second alternative matches the input WS-sensitive and will therefore only be matched if the identifier is directly followed by the bracket.

See [here](https://github.com/almondtools/antlr4multichannel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/almondtools/antlr4multichannel/MultiChannelTokenStream.java) for the implementation of the `MultiChannelTokenStream` that is mentioned in the linked question.